# Pandas combining dataframes based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to turn multiple dataframes into a single one based on the values in the first column, but not every dataframe has the same values in the first column. Take this example:

```
df1:
A    4
B    6
C    8

df2:
A    7
B    4
F    3

full_df:
A    4    7
B    6    4
C    8
F         3
```

How do I do this using python and pandas?

Comment: You can use Pandas' [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas merge with outer join

```
df1.merge(df2,on =['first_column'],how='outer')
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using append.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), remembering to align indices:

```
res = pd.concat([df1.set_index(0), df2.set_index(0)], axis=1)

print(res)

     1    1
A  4.0  7.0
B  6.0  4.0
C  8.0  NaN
F  NaN  3.0
```